# Does get-s3object download the entire object(s) data to memory from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

We are using `get-s3object` to grab all the objects in a AWS bucket. This has caused a large number of overages in the amount of data being transferred out of AWS S3 to the internet. Does get-s3object store the entire object content in memory? It seems the alternative is to use `get-s3objectmetadata` however it does not support batch mode.

The purpose of the script is to only grab metadata about each object in the bucket. There could be 1000s of objects so looking to scale and do with the least amount of api calls / data transfer. It will run on a machine outside the AWS environment

Comment: Thanks for the help , just gave it some edits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Get-S3Object` Cmdlet seems to have two options:

- `GetMultipleObjects` (which calls `ListObjects`) returns a list of objects (but not their contents), *and*
- `GetSingleObject` (which calls `GetObject`) retrieves the contents of a specific object

If `GetMultipleObjects` does not return the level of information you require, then `Get-S3ObjectMetadata` (which calls `HEAD` on the object) can be used to retrieve metadata about a **single object**. It does *not* download the contents of the object.